# Change of Variable Proof in Folland

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am reviewing Folland's proof of the following standard result and I have a question on one part.

Suppose $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^{n}$; $G:\Omega \to \mathbb R^{n}$ is a diffeomorphism on $\Omega$; $f\in \mathcal L^{1}(G(\Omega))$. Then,

$$\int _{G(\Omega)}f(x)dx=\int _{\Omega}f\circ G(x)\cdot\vert\det G'(x)\vert dx.$$

The main idea is to establish the inequality

$$\tag1 m(G(Q))\leq \int _{Q}\vert\det G'(x)\vert dx$$

where $Q$ is a cube in $\Omega$.

Folland does this by observing that for any $\epsilon>0$ we may choose $\delta>0$ so that, as soon as $Q$ is subdivided into $\left \{ Q_k \right \}^{n}_{k=1}$, where the $Q_k$ are cubes with disjoint interiors, of side length $<\delta$, with centers $x_k$, then the following holds:

$$\tag 2m(G(Q))\leq (1+\epsilon)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\vert\det G'(x_k)\vert m(Q_k).$$

He then claims that $(1)$ follows from this, upon letting $\epsilon ,\delta\to 0$ and appealing to the uniform continuity of $\vert \det G'\vert $. This seems like a bit of handwaving to me. Or at least the claim deserves more rigor.

Or am I missing something simple here?

In any case, it seems easier just to note that $\vert \det G'\vert $ is Riemann integrable on $Q$, so we may write, with $P_k$ the partition of $Q$ determined by $Q_k$:

$$\tag3 m(G(Q))\leq (1+\epsilon )\sum_{k=1}^{n}\vert\det G'(x_k)\vert m(Q_k)\leq (1+\epsilon )U(\vert \det G'\vert , P_k).$$

Then, given an an arbitrary partition of $Q$, there is a refinement to a partition determined by some $\left \{ Q_k \right \}^{N}_{k=1}$ where the side length of each $Q_k<\delta$, from which it follows immediately from $(3)$ that

$$\tag4 m(G(Q))\leq (1+\epsilon )\overline \int _{Q}\vert\det G'(x)\vert dx=(1+\epsilon )\int _{Q}\vert\det G'(x)\vert dx,$$

which is what we want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\vert\det G'(x_k)\vert m(Q_k) = \int_{Q_k}\vert\det G'(x_k)\vert dx \le \int_{Q_k} \vert\det G'(x)\vert dx + \epsilon m(Q_k)$$

If you assume in addition that $\delta $ is chosen (using uniform continuity) so that

$$\bigg|\vert\det G'(x)\vert  -\vert\det G'(y)\vert\bigg| <\epsilon$$

for all $x, y\in Q_k$. Then

$$m(G(Q)) \le (1+\epsilon)\bigg( \int_Q \vert\det G'(x)\vert dx + \epsilon m(Q)\bigg)$$

Now take $\epsilon \to 0$ and you are done.

It is interesting to know that when one proves that continuous function on a compact set is Riemann integrable, one uses uniform continuity. So whether or not your proof (which is correct) is easier than mine (which I guess is what the author has in mind) depends on the definition of easiness.